# Having trouble understanding some class code in python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to programming and am having some trouble understanding the output of this code.

```
#testclass.py

class TestCount:
    count = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = TestCount.count
        self.attr2 = TestCount.count + 1
        TestCount.count += 2

x = TestCount()
y = TestCount()

print(x.attr1, x.attr2)
print(y.attr1, y.attr2)
```

This is a rework of a larger example out of a book I'm currently learning out of.  When this code is ran it gives:

```
0 1
2 3
```

When I expect it to be:

```
0 1
0 1
```

What is the fundamental that I'm missing here?  I see y as a new instance but it seems to be picking up where x left off.  Sorry if I'm not explaining myself clearly but I'm new at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` is a property of the **class**, not the instance. That means this value is **shared** by all instances.

You are initializing `attr1` with  `TestCount.count` and later increasing it by `2`. So the second instance will start with `attr1` being set to `2`, for the third instance `4`, etc.

If you want both properties (`attr1` and `attr2`) to be initialized with `0` and `1`, you should do so:

```
class TestCount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 0
        self.attr2 = 1
```

For ore information, I suggest to read the [*Classes*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) section in the official Python tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, this helped make a little more sense out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined `TestCount.count` in the class body it becames a static variable that is shared among **all objects**. So the `TestCount.count` of `x` is **same object** as the `TestCount.count` of `y`.

This is what happens:

```
x = TestCount()
#x.attr1 = 0
#x.attr2 = 0 + 1
#TestCount.count += 2 #TestCount.count is now 2, it was 0

y = TestCount()
#y.attr1 = 2
#y.attr2 = 2 + 1
```